# 24 hours format from date/time field

Tags: apex, trigger, datetime

I need to extract the hours from a Date/Time field in the format: `12:00, 13:00, 14:00, 16:00`.

Right now I'm using this function:

```
"Date/time field".format('hh:mm:ss a');
```

But the hours comes in the form of `4:00 PM`. How can I change the format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to change your formula to look like:

```
"Date/time field".format('kk:mm:ss');
```

See the [Java Simple Date Time Format Page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more.